# How to give darkening effect to button when clicked or hold in android?

Tags: android

How do I give darkening effect to a button when clicked or long clicked on it, just as in default contacts app. The effect is also shown when clicked on any menu item.

Comment: You mean the "ripple effect"?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: Yes @cricket_007 thanks

Comment: http://guides.codepath.com/android/ripple-animation